# How to find the P(A|B) of two random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables

If we have 2 random variables, A = {1,3,7} and B = {2,3,6}
where p(1) = 0.12; p(2) = 0.22; p(3) =0.11; p(6) = 0.15; p(7) = 0.11 .

How do we calculate P(A|B)? Is it different from how we calculate P(event1|event2)?

I am more interested in the procedure, than in the actual result of the example. Could anyone please explain it to me, or share useful links?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ random **variables** (as you claim) or random **events** (as it looks like they are)?

Comment: @5xum "Events" suffice ("random events" would be something more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

The conditional probability is defined by
\begin{equation*}
P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}
\end{equation*}
so it is the probability of, knowing $B$ has happened, $A$ happens; from here the intersection in the denominator and the normalizing with the "new event space" $B$.

So for your example,
\begin{equation*}
P(A|B) = \frac{P(\{ 3 \})}{P(\{2,3,6 \})}
\end{equation*}